# How to get updated data in google spread sheet from MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have given a task to get data in Google Spread Sheet from Microsoft SQL Server database table.

Is there any script or tools available. Please let me know. I shall be highly thankful for this.

Regards,
SAzam

Answer (score 1):

You can get data in Google SpreadSheet from a Microsoft SQL Server database table, but you'll need to install the "Database Browser" add-on. After install just refresh the Google SpreadSheet and then go to add-ons tab -> Database Browser -> Start. A window will appear and you'll have to choose what RDBMS you use and then insert the connection credentials.